# Best plot to accompany unpaired 2-group test

Tags: data-visualization, method-comparison

If one plot is to be recommended for an article, from statistical point of view, which plot is best to convey information in cases of unpaired 2-group comparisons. Is it boxplot, violin plot, histograms or density curves? Or a combination of these or some other plot? Or you think they all will convey the required message equally well?

Comment: How much data do you have? One complaint people sometimes make is barplots / boxplots where there are only a few data, & you could have just as easily shown the data themselves. Also, are the distributions similar & fairly well-behaved?

Comment: Can we not have one recommendation for all kinds of data? Which plot will be best for most kinds of unpaired 2-group numeric data?

Comment: No, there isn't going to be a one-size-fits-all solution. The best visualization will depend on properties of your data.